# String fraction to numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string that represents a fraction and I want to extract the numerator and denominator.

```
var stringFraction = '99/99 (100%)';
var fraction = stringFraction.split(' ')[0].split('/');
console.log(0, Number(fraction[0]));
console.log(1, Number(fraction[1]));
```

This works fine but I'm wondering if a regex would be better?

Comment: Better in what way?

Comment: If this is always your input, I'd argue a regex is worse

Comment: Code review questions are specifically off-topic on SO, mostly because answers tend to be highly subjective.

Comment: Do you have to account for non-standard or invalid input?

Comment: My guess is that will execute faster than a RegExp, as the instructions are very specific.

Answer (score 2):

Using a regex, you would be able to go for a simple match/find.

In your case, you first split the fraction itself from the remaining part, to then split again on the '/'.

In other words: a regex would allow you to reduce your code to a single match operation.

See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) for some guidance how that would work.

Of course, you could also do that specific "matching" in a more manual mode:

- get the string from 0 to index-1 of '/'
- get the string from '/' to ' '

In other words, there are plenty of ways to retrieve that information. Each one has different pros and cons, and the real answer for a newbie learning this stuff: make experiments, and try them all.

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason you can't do trimming and all with a single regex
without having to go through the gyrations with split.

Try this

`/0*(\d+)\s*\/\s*0*(\d+)/`

Formatted

```
 0*
 ( \d+ )                       # (1)
 \s* / \s* 
 0*
 ( \d+ )                       # (2)
```

JS sample

```js
var strSample = 
  "0039/99 (100%)\n" +
  "00/000 (100%)\n" +
  "junk 102 / 487\n";

var NumerDenomRx = new RegExp( "0*(\\d+)\\s*/\\s*0*(\\d+)", "g");
var match;

while ( match=NumerDenomRx.exec( strSample ))
{
  console.log("numerator = ", match[1] );
  console.log("denominator = ", match[2] );
  console.log( "-------------------------" );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If all strings have the same pattern

```
var stringFraction = '99/99 (100%)';
var fraction = stringFraction.match(/\d+/g); // result = ["99", "99", "100"];
```

Now  technically this is shorter than `split`ing it, 15 vs 26 letters/signs/spaces, but only if the length of the array doesn't bother you. Otherwise you will have to chain extra method

```
.slice(1,-1)
```

that's +12 extra signs/letters. If the string is more complex

```
var fraction = stringFraction.match(/\d+\/\d+/)[0].split('/');
```

There are endless variations how to solve it really

P.S. Unless you got more complex strings, regex is not needed.